# Excel cell with text and numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need a cell that has both a number and text to be linked to another cell and when the number in that other cell changes, the number in the cell with text also changes.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Could you expand a bit on what you are trying to achieve here? Please [edit your question to](https://superuser.com/posts/1292948/edit) include sample data, and an illustration of what you would like to aachieve. Thanks :)

Comment: There are some tips on [how to ask a good question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, if your question has been solved, it's good form to use the tick next to the best answer to show that it's been accepted.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in at least two ways.  Assuming that a plain number (`1`, for example) is in cell `A1`:

- If you enter `=A1 & " My text"` in a cell, it would take the string value `"1 My text"`.  The `&` operator converts the number to a string, and concatenates it to the text in the formula.
- If you enter `=A1` in a cell, it will have the same numeric value as cell `A1`. However, you can then add a [custom number format](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/create-or-delete-a-custom-number-format-78f2a361-936b-4c03-8772-09fab54be7f4#bm2) to make text appear in the same cell. Go to Format Cells / Number / Custom, then enter a format string like `# "My text"`.

In both cases, the cell will show `1 My text`, but in the second case, you can still treat it as a number, and use its value in calculations.